# Using SQL commands in Python

Tags: sqlite, pandas

I used the following code in iPython in order to get some information from a database's table in the form of a pandas dataframe.

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('-----.db') 
a = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM table1, con) 
c= con.cursor
```

I have table 1 as a dataframe named a. However, I need to carry out a number of inner joins between different tables from the database. My question would be how to use SQL commands within iPython using these dataframes? I tried c.execute(''' sql command for inner join''') but the error says that the dataframes mentioned are not tables.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just write the full sql command directly using read_sql.

```
sql = """
select col1 from 
tablea inner join tableb
on tablea.col2 = tableb.col2
where tablea.col3 < 10
limit 10
"""
a = pd.read_sql(sql, con)
```